# Why are two <cr> characters required when executing this highlighting toggle command?

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, normal-mode, highlight

I use this keymapping toggle to highlighting on and off, but when I originally found it, the author did not list two `<cr>` at the end of the command. I found that if I didn't have two `<cr>` there, then I was required to press <kbd>Return</kbd> after my keymapping. Why? ... because now that I can get the macro (wrong term?) to execute, my cursor advances to the next line after executing the mapping.

```
highlight OverLength ctermbg=gray
match OverLength /\%81v.\+/
let OLstate = 1
nnoremap oi : if (OLstate == 0) \| match OverLength /%81v.\+/ \| else \| match OverLength /%9999v/ \| endif \| let OLstate = 1 - OLstate <cr> <cr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
: ... endif <cr> :let OLstate = 1 - OLstate <cr>
```

instead of

```
: ... endif \| let OLstate = 1 - OLstate <cr>
```

That is, **`<cr>`** after the `endif`, a **`:`** before `let` and **`<cr>`** after the `let` statement. There are two commands.

I'm using `vim 7.4`, plain vanilla, no `.vimrc`, no plugins.

Comment: By golly, that was it! ... so to make sure I understand this right: It was failing because the first `:if` command should be entered and executed (terminating in that `<cr>`), and then the `:let` command should be entered and executed - but my original code had one long command (actually two nested commands?) not properly executing in order... resulting in the need for two `<cr>`s to execute first the inner-nested command and then the outer-nested command?